# Undefined offset: 5

Tags: php, html, undefined, offset

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $table = array ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
    $count = count($table); 
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    $rows = 5;
    for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i = $i + $rows)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        for($z = 0; $z < $rows; $z++)
        {
            if ($table[$i + $z] !=0)
                echo "<td>This is row {$table[$i + $z]}</td></tr>";
            else
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>"
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I've been trying to make work for a while, and while everything else is OK, the problem occurs when I run it. It shows the table as I want it, but under the table it posts:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in [file location] on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in [file location] on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in [file location] on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in [file location] on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in [file location] on line 22
```

I know the problem is around the "!=0" value, but no matter what I change it into, it either flushes the whole effort or repeats the same message.

Answer (score 2):

1. You missed `;` in the following statement.

   ```
   echo "</table>"
   ```
2. You are iterating in steps of 5. `$i + $rows` and your `$table` can go at most `$table[4]`.
3. The error/notice is because of the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten the same error code, but I managed to find the issue. The error message you're getting has to do with arrays. It seems you're referencing to an undefined array[key]: 
`for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i = $i + $rows)`. `$i = $i + $rows` is the culprit. Example: `$i = 0` and `$rows=5;` so `0 + 5 = 5`  so array[5] and this doesn't exist in the array. It only goes to 4 with the `$table` array. 
Hope this helps you along and/or someone else.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $the_file = file($_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name']);
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($myfile); ++$i){
        echo $myfile[$i] . "<br/>";
        echo "Line " . ( $i + 1 ) . " is  " .strlen($myfile[$i]) . " characters long<br/>";
    }
}
?>


<form method="post" action="myphp.php" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
    <input type="file" name="the_file" value="Yes"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="No"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful if you provide some explanation of what you are doing and why it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think who posted this problem has solved it already. Just a little bit change on this line `for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i = $i + $rows)` can solve the problem.

`for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i = $i + $rows) // for($i=0; $i < $count; $i = $i + $rows)` use this.